# Iterate over Array of Objects and Return Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am trying to return a list of titles of objects in Rails, however I keep getting the entire object returned instead of the title attribute.

loe is the object which has an attribute which is a list of articles (named article), each article is itself an object with an attribute called title.

```
<%= loe.article.each { |x| print x.title } %>
```

is how I am currently attempting to do the iteration, but this returns the entire list of articles.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) to invoke the `title` method on each and create a new array with the results:

```
loe.article.map(&:title)
```

The above is shorthand for

```
loe.article.map{ |o| o.title }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the ERB tag like '`<%=` ' means that you're asking ERB to display the result of that expression (above and beyond the fact that you're calling `print` inside the block). And a call to an Enumerable method like `each` will return the original array, which is what you're seeing.

Change the tag to `<%` (remove the `=`) and you should be good to go.

Comment: the only answer to question

Answer (score 1):

`loe.article.map {|x| x.title}` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

```
class LOE < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :loe
end

loe.articles.select(:title).collect{|a| a.title}
```

`map` and `collect` are aliases, and you can call `select(:fieldname)` on an AREL to return just that field. You still get objects, but they're read-only and are populated with whatever the select returned, so to get the array of titles you need to do the `collect`.