# Rails3 multiple queries on arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.2, conditional-statements

Rails 3.2.13 using postgre application.  Attempting to generate an array from a where clause to use in a subsequent query.

```
User has_and_belongs_to_many :contractors 
Contractor has_and_belongs_to_many :users  
Building has_many :contractors 
Contractor belongs_to :building
```

a controller action states

```
@contractors = Contractor.where(['contractorusers.user_id = ?', current_user]).joins(:users).select("building_id")
```

Running the command in terminal generates the proper array of relationships

```
[#<Contractor building_id: 55>, #<Contractor building_id: 49>]
```

However the subsequent query needs the array of building ids

```
@buildings = Building.where(['id IN (?)', @contractors])
```

calls an array of relations which is interpreted as NULL

How can @contractors be transformed into an array of values only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 'select', but 'pluck',  The latter extracts the value and makes it an array.

```
@contractors = Contractor.where(['contractorusers.user_id = ?', current_user]).joins(:users).pluck("building_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call the accessor for building_id on each Contractor object in your @contractors result

Array#map it the most beautiful way to do that: [Iterate over Array of Objects and Return Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906922/iterate-over-array-of-objects-and-return-attributes)

```
@buildings = Building.where(['id IN (?)', @contractors.map(&:building_id))
```

I'm a ruby newbie myself so I'm prepared to be corrected.

Comment: That's returning undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass  I see how that is consistent - the context seems off: the query returns an array of relations, not objects.

Comment: So wouldn't a through association work better to do what you want?
`User has_many :buildings, through: :contractors`

Comment: doing that with the contractoruser class